# Can't download snapshot artifacts when version is specified by range

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, nexus

In POM could be specified wanted range of artifact version (which in next step will be downloaded by maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies):

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibi-test</artifactId>
    <version>[0.1.4-SNAPSHOT,0.2.0)</version>
</dependency>
```

Problem is that *hibi-test* has NO releases on my Nexus, - only few SNAPSHOTS (locked timestamp snapshots). I've checked this POM on artifacts which have both releases and snapshots and it worked good, but in that case I've got only:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Test: Could not resolve dependencies for project my.group:Test:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact my.group:hibi-test:jar:0.1.4
```

Snapshot repository in POM is defined.
I've tried various combination of range, enabling snapshots and versions:unlock-snapshot, but it didn't work. When I passed only *0.1.4-SNAPSHOT* artifact *hibi-test-0.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar* was downloaded correctly.

What I need here? :)

Answer (score 0):

is 0.2.0 the latest version?

Maybe you should try to change your range of versions.

Try this:

```
<version> [0.1.4,0.2.0) </version>
```